# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10894: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, shapely, folium, fiona

I was following this example (https://github.com/geodocker/geodocker-jupyter-geopyspark/blob/master/notebooks/sanfranmvp.ipynb ) so I can replicate similar output, every was successful except the last, I have tried all possible tweak but no success, please can someone help tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is the last step of the code using folium to view my map in Jupyter notebook.

```
m = folium.Map(tiles='OpenStreetMap', location=map_center, zoom_start=zoom)

folium.TileLayer(tiles=tms.url_pattern, attr='GeoPySpark', name='Weighted layer', overlay=True).add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson('data/bars.geojson', name='Bars', style_function=lambda x: {'radius': 2, 'color': 'red'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson('data/cafes.geojson', name='Cafes', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson('data/transit.geojson', name='Transit', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'green'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)

m
```

Here is the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-42944e2ceb84> in <module>()
     11 m = folium.Map(tiles='OpenStreetMap', location=map_center, zoom_start=zoom)
     12 folium.TileLayer(tiles=tms.url_pattern, attr='GeoPySpark', name='Weighted layer', overlay=True).add_to(m)
---> 13 folium.GeoJson('data/bars.geojson', name='Bars', style_function=lambda x: {'radius': 2, 'color': 'red'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)
     14 folium.GeoJson('data/cafes.geojson', name='Cafes', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)
     15 folium.GeoJson('data/transit.geojson', name='Transit', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'green'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)


/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, name, overlay, control, smooth_factor, highlight_function)
    480             else:  # This is a filename
    481                 with open(data) as f:
--> 482                     self.data = json.loads(f.read())
    483         elif data.__class__.__name__ in ['GeoDataFrame', 'GeoSeries']:
    484             self.embed = True


/usr/lib64/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10894: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Apparently that file contains non-ASCII characters.  That's not surprising, because GeoJSON files are allowed to contain non-ASCII characters encoded as UTF-8. Try using `folium.GeoJson( json.load( open('data/bars.geojson') ), ... )` instead of relying on the internal file `open` and `read` calls. Since `json.load()` expects to see UTF-8 content, it should not blow up on non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ottomeister, i tried the suggestion you made, but i still get the same error.

Comment: Ugh.  Are you sure it's blowing up on the same file, `bars.geojson` on line 13?  (I ask because I downloaded the files and I see that the `cafes.geojson` file also contains non-ASCII UTF-8 characters, so it would throw the same error and would need the same adjustment.)

Comment: @ottomeister UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-355a70a20a07> in <module>()
     13 m = folium.Map(tiles='OpenStreetMap', location=map_center, zoom_start=zoom)
     14 folium.TileLayer(tiles=tms.url_pattern, attr='GeoPySpark', name='Weighted layer', overlay=True).add_to(m)
---> 15 folium.GeoJson(json.load(open('data/bars.geojson')), name='Bars', style_function=lambda x: {'radius': 2, 'color': 'red'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)

Comment: I wonder if this is a side effect of Python 3's strict interpretation of text encoding. Can you try it with `open('data/bars.geojson')` changed to `open('data/bars.geojson', 'rb')` to force binary (non-text) handling and avoid an attempt at an ASCII decode as the file is being read ?

Comment: @ottomeister it still didnt work, is this working on your end using folium?

Comment: @ottomeister i finally fixed the problem. i was able to convert the geojson feature collection by adding the encode parameter. Thanks for your contribution, it really helped. see my final addition. folium.GeoJson(json.load(open('data/bars.geojson', encoding = 'utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution to the issue, with the help of @ottomeister, i was able to narrow down my research which led me to the solution.

```
m = folium.Map(tiles='OpenStreetMap', location=map_center, zoom_start=zoom)
folium.TileLayer(tiles=tms.url_pattern, attr='MYGeoPySpark', name='Weighted layer', overlay=True).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(json.load(open('data/bars.geojson', encoding = 'utf-8')), name='Bars', style_function=lambda x: {'radius': 2, 'color': 'red'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(json.load(open('data/cafes.geojson', encoding = 'utf-8')), name='Cafes', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'orange'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)
folium.GeoJson(json.load(open('data/transit.geojson', encoding = 'utf-8')), name='Transit', style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'green'}, overlay=True).add_to(m)

m
```